# How to run a second command after a for loop in Windows CMD in a single line

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I want to execute this commands in a single line with [ShellExecuteExW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shellexecuteexa):

```
for /l %i in (0,1,20) do (tasklist | findstr terminatedProcess && exit || ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul) && echo timeout
```

The script is supposed to wait 20 seconds for `terminatedProcess` to terminate and exit. If after 20 seconds the process is not terminated, it should execute another command (for illustration purposes `echo timeout` was used)

In reality, `echo timeout` is executed every iteration.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Put an open parenthesis `(` in front of `for /l` and a closing one `)` in front of `&& echo timeout`, then the latter is no longer art of the loop body...

Comment: In addition, I think your logic is wrong: if the process is still running, `tasklist` will still return it, so `findstr` will find it and return zero as exit code, hence `&&` and `||` behind `findstr` should be exchanged; also I would let `tasklist` do the main filtering by `/FI "ImageName eq terminatedProcess`, so perhaps `findstr` was maybe not even necessary...

Answer (score 0):

Totally untested:

```
for /L %%i in (0,1,20) do  timeout /t 1 >nul&tasklist|findstr "terminatedprocessname">nul&if errorlevel 1 (exit /b 0) else if %%i==20 echo timed out&exit /b 1
```

Noting that `findstr` will return errorlevel `0` if the processname is found (therefore it hasn't yet been terminated)